# Strange calls to modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:inView: (UIDataSourceModelAssociation)

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm currently implementing automatic state preservation/restoration in an iOS6-only app.

For a restoration of a table view, I added the `UIDataSourceModelAssociation` protocol to my table view controllers and implemented

`- (NSString *)modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)idx inView:(UIView *)view`

and

`- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForElementWithModelIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier inView:(UIView *)view`

When pressing the home button, the state preservation methods, including `modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:iView:`, are getting called as expected and return valid identifier strings for the given index paths.

When killing the app and relaunching it, state restoration works more or less. I.e. the app re-opens the correct table view. However, the table view is always scrolled to the top, even when it was scrolled to another position before.

Here's the implementation of the `UIDataSourceModelAssociation` methods in my table view controller. Nothing fancy going on in there (the `NdlFriend::accountUid`property returns a unique identifier string for a given NdlFriend record):

```
#pragma mark - UIDataSourceModelAssociation
- (NSString *)modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)idx inView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSString* identifier = nil;
    NSArray* content = self.contentArray;

    // Sometimes idx might be nil...
    if(idx && idx.row<content.count)
    {
        NdlFriend* friend = content[idx.row];
        identifier=friend.accountUid;
    }
    return identifier;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForElementWithModelIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier inView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath=nil;
    NSArray* content = self.contentArray;
    NSInteger count = content.count;
    for(NSInteger i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        NdlFriend* friend = content[i];
        if([identifier isEqualToString:friend.accountUid])
        {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

I set break points in both methods.

To test the methods, I opened the table view and scrolled down a little bit. Then, when pressing the home button:

- `modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:inView:` gets called once, with the index path of the top most visible row. The method returns the correct uid for this row.

So far so good.

Then I stop and relaunch the app. Here's what happens (I'm especially puzzled by the first hit break point):

- `modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:inView:` gets called, with `nil` as index path (the view argument contains the correct pointer of the table view).
- `indexPathForElementWithModelIdentifier:inView:` gets called with a valid identifier string (and a valid index path is returned by the method).
- `indexPathForElementWithModelIdentifier:inView:` gets called again (with the same identifier string).
- The table view is refreshed, but scrolled to the very top.

Does someone know, why the restoration of the scroll position fails? Does maybe the call of `modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:inView:` with `nil` as indexPath has something to do with it (or is this normal behavior).

Comment: While restoration of the table view scroll position (mostly) works now in iOS 9, the broken behaviour described in the question where `modelIdentifierForElementAtIndexPath:inView:` _gets called, with nil as index path_ sometimes occurs when an empty table view is restored, resulting in a _bad access_ exception. A workaround is to change the method signature to accept a nillable `NSIndexPath!` and guard against `nil` (by returning `nil`), even though it **should never happen**! (Alternatively, to avoid the warning, returning `nil` if `numberOfRowsInSection(0)` is zero also works.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in iOS 6 regarding state restoration of Table Views in Navigation Controllers.

You can see the open radar here: [rdar://13438788](https://openradar.appspot.com/13438788)

As you can see, it's a duplicate, so Apple are aware of this.

Also, see this next link, the guy who posted that open radar also did this blog post, it has the suggested workarounds that the Apple Engineers told him.

It makes the state preservation/restoration for me not such an enjoyable feature to implement, although remember, this is for your users ! So you should just do the workaround anyway.

Note there are 2 workarounds, one for the table view's view information to restore (scroll offset for example), and another workaround for the use when implementing `UIDataSourceModelAssociation` which is your case.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/04/07/bug-table-view-state-not-restored-when-embedded-in-navigation-controller.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem you're having of the table view's scroll position resetting has to do with the UIDataSourceModelAssociation methods.

I believe there's a bug with a table view controller embedded in a nav controller, that causes it to reset its scroll position after restoration.  As I understand it, if the cells in your table view don't reorder, you don't need to implement the UIDataSourceModelAssociation methods and you should get the scroll position "for free" (i.e. as long as you've opted into state preservation and set the restorations IDs). I can't really confirm this explicitly from the documentation, except to point out that UITableView descends from UIScrollView, which saves its scroll position. I've tested that if you set the table view controller to be the root controller, or embed a table view controller in a tab bar controller, then the scroll position *is* restored.

I've filed a bug report, you should too, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Aky and this might indeed be a bug in iOS 6. See my answer on a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567551/322548

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not performing an asynchronous fetch on your data.  If you are fetching your data from viewDidLoad, make sure that you use a [myManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{}] call instead of a [myManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{}].

It may be that you have a race condition where self.contentArray is empty when indexPathForElementWithModelIdentifier gets called.