# Table view doesn't restore scroll position if embedded in Nav Controller (iOS 6 state preservation/restoration)

Tags: ios6

I've being playing with iOS 6 state preservation/restoration and I've run into a weird case. If I embed a table view controller inside a navigation controller in a Storyboarded app, the table view (even after my having scrolled down) resets its scroll position to the top after I test state restoration (using the "Press Home Button followed by stop and run in Xcode" routine). This is in Xcode 4.5.1 building for iOS 6.0.

I've carried out the required steps to support restoration: I've checked that encodeRestorableStateWithCoder and e encodeRestorableStateWithCoder get called in my table view controller subclass (and yes, I do call super when I run that check).

**If I delete the Navigation Controller from the Storyboard and instead embed my table view controller in a Tab Bar Controller, the scroll position *is* preserved.**

Any idea what I could be doing wrong, if anything? (I'm inclined to think it's a bug.)

Here are the exact steps to reproduce this issue (for Xcode 4.5.1, iOS 6.0)

1. Create a new iPhone project with an Empty Template with ARC enabled.
2. Create a storyboard file called Storyboard, and set it as the app's "Main Storyboard" in the Project Editor > Targets > Summary pane
3. Drag a Navigation Controller into the Storyboard scene

(4) In Appdelegate.m, replace the code in the @implementation section to read

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

(5) Create a UITableViewController subclass without a XIB, call it TableViewController, and replace the code in the .m file with:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@implementation TableViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1000;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

(6) In the Storyboard, change the class of the table view controller from UITableViewController to TableViewController in the Identity Inspector in the utilities pane.

(7) In the Storyboard, assign the cell reuse identifier "Cell" to the table view cell via the Attributes Inspector.

(8) In the Storyboard, assign Restoration IDs to the navigation controller, the table view controller and the table view in the Identity Inspector.  I set the Storyboard IDs to be "Nav Controller", "Table View Controller" and "Table View" respectively and checked the box to "Use Storyboard ID" as the Restoration ID for each.

Build the app, scroll some ways down the table view, click on the Home Button, stop the app in Xcode and then run again via Xcode.

The table view should be scrolled to the point before the Home Button was pressed, but it isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIKit state preservation not restoring scroll offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613203/uikit-state-preservation-not-restoring-scroll-offset)